# Simple recursion of decision tree [Python]

Tags: python, recursion

I'm learning recursion and I have the following tree:

```
    #                cough
    #          Yes /       \ No
    #        fever           healthy
    #   Yes /     \ No
    # influenza   cold
```

with the following code:

```
def diagnose_helper(symptoms, node, symptoms_checked):

        if node.positive_child == None and node.negative_child == None:
            print(node.data, "In")
            return node.data
        for symp in symptoms:
            if symp == node.data and symp not in symptoms_checked:
                symptoms_checked.append(symp)
                return diagnose_helper(symptoms, node.positive_child,
                                                symptoms_checked)
            else:
                return diagnose_helper(symptoms, node.negative_child,
                                                symptoms_checked)
```

that check if a symptom is in a list or not, and returns the current situation.
I.e for this input:

```
diagnose_helper(["cough, fever"], root, [])
```

it should return "influenza" because cough -> yes and fever -> yes, but it actually returns cold.
I can't seem to find why, if anyone has any idea i'll take it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function will check only the first element in the symptoms, because you have a return in both branches of the if statement. Maybe try like this:

```
def diagnose_helper(symptoms, node):

    if node.positive_child == None and node.negative_child == None:
        print(node.data, "In")
        return node.data

    if node.data in symptoms:
        return diagnose_helper(symptoms, node.positive_child)
    else:
        return diagnose_helper(symptoms, node.negative_child)
```